# How do I figure out why Python is throwing this non-descriptive error in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, scipy, python-2.7

I'm making graphs using scipy on python 2.7 on Windows 7 64 bit.  I installed it from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

When running scripts, I'm periodically getting error boxes that say:

> Title:
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
>
> Message:
>
> Runtime Error! Program:
>   C:\Python27\pythonw.exe
>
> This application has requested the
>   Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
>   way. Please contact the application's
>   support team for more information

And that's it.  How do I begin to figure out what is causing this error?

Comment: Unfortunately my crystal ball is currently being repaired and so it's not going to be possible to work out what the problem is from this message. Please supply more details.

Comment: could you supply a minimal selection of code that exhibits the fault

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755931/microsoft-visual-c-runtime-error-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You could consider installing Visual Studio, and build and install Python and SciPy with debug symbols. When Python subsequently crashes, if I'm not completely mistaken Windows should be giving you the option of debugging it in Visual Studio.

Otherwise, I'd ask for assistance on one of the [SciPy mailing lists](http://www.scipy.org/Mailing_Lists).