# this application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, runtime-error

I am working with python 2.7.18 and when I run my code this error appears telling "This application has requested the runtime too ...", I closed all my codes and write this simple code which is a simple plotting of a mathematical function, but again I came up with this error, don't[image] know how to solve it. The code and error picture is attached here, does anyone know how to solve it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you importing numpy? You never use it.

Comment: Because at first I was tended to use np.arange ...

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes it is just a simple code for testing purpose

Comment: The problem is not the code I think there is something else making this error!

Comment: Probably, but there's not enough information here for us to know what it is.

Comment: same as me! Some websites say the problem may be due to Microsoft visual C++ redistributable, but I have 2010,2008 and 2017 versions in my pc

Comment: Thanks for your comment Exploore x 1, frankly I could not follow the instruction mentioned there, now I uninstalled all my Microsoft visual c++ tools and downloaded and installed them again, now just sometimes the error appears, but my code runs properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following steps are recommended to solve the problem:

1. Run cmd as admin and execute this code :
   `bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVa 3072`
   Restart your computer and then see if the problem solved
   If not do the 2nd one
   2.Open control pannel> program and features > repair all versions of Microsof visual c++ then restart pc and test
   3.uninstall all the Microsoft visual c++ versions and download and install them again from Microsoft.com restart and test
2. Go to sereby.org website and download runtime in download section. Install it and most often, one of these will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is most possibly because somewhere in your python library, and even possible from your python runtime,

[Check to this other stackoverflow Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19130799/14867730)

Comment: I've already checked there, didn't solve the problem, thanks for your answer

Comment: If you think the answer is in another question you should flag it as a duplicate, not post an answer just containing a link.